# Ctrl-Alt-Fx doesn't work: Getty / VT vs X session bug (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, xorg, login, systemd, virtual-console

I've run into problems with virtual terminals.
I boot up, log in via VT, startx.
Next, I'm going to another VT (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>), login there too, and exit that vt (tty2).
What happens next is strange - I'm redirected to tty1 where my X session was started from. The X either pops back or doesn't. When it does, usually my mouse and keyboard do not work, although the touchpad seems ok.
At this point I am unable to go back to a VT too, seems like none of them are there anymore.

When it doesn't - I'm unable to even reboot via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> (multiple times (>7)), or via REISUB sysrq.

The machine keeps working at this point and it is accessible via SSH.

The power button is configured to initiate reboot, so that's the only option. When I use power button to reboot, I see systemd going through shutdown procedure, which most of the times hangs on random things. Sometimes even hiting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>  7 times to force reboot doesn't help, as it just prints "forcibly rebooting" and then keeps hanging.

Other scenarios:

**a)**

- boot up, go to tty2 and login there
- login to tty3 and exit
  Result: I'm back on tty1, tty3 is inactive - have to hit enter to spawn it.

**b)**

- boot up, go to tty2, login there and run e.g. top
- login to tty1 and startx

Result: I'm unable to get back to tty2. The only combination that does something is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> (the tty1 which is taken by x session). This leaves with blank screen, I'm no longer able to go to X or tty2, or do anything except for hitting the power button.

Therefore - there are 2 problems, but I'd like to first understand and resolve the first issue - getting back to X and VT.
I looked in the logs, but I no longer understand what is happening as getty is a systemd service somehow connected to a "login" session, and I also found some info on some systemd-getty-generator. As I say - I no longer understand this, so I'd appreciate any hints how to resolve that.

Did anybody observe similar behavior?

18.04 LTS, Dell e7440.

Comment: Why? What is on topic, then?

Comment: I think in 18.04 only Ctrl+Alt+F3 through Ctrl+Alt+F7 can be used for a console login.

Comment: Please see the help section of the site.

Comment: @user68186 **bug reports** are offtopic, but if we aren't sure if it's an actual bug or not then it's still on topic here; if we ultimately deem that it is a bug then we can close it as a bug report

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Interesting, is it documented anywhere? I'm currently on debian testing and this works without any quirks. I found some bug report against systemd that I suspect might be related: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8582

However, I'm still not sure if that's the real reason.